# How to update css urls on deployment?

Tags: angular, sass, angular8

How can I update the `css` url on deploy the build? because I am placing the bundle in to `app1` folder. so image should be supplied from `app1` url,

current:

```
.home {
    background: url('./assets/images/body-bg.jpg') no-repeat left center;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

expecting on deployment to update like :

```
.home {
    background: url('app1/body-bg.jpg') no-repeat left center;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

I am keeping my package.json build like this:

`"ng build --prod --base-href=/app1/ --output-hashing none"`
But not getting any valid update. any help please?

Comment: I don't get it, why are you placing your images under 'app1/body-bg.jpg', if you have set properly in the package.json the assets folder this will be built automatically and using the path like `./assets/images/body-bg.jpg` will work perfectly

Comment: @ZetaPR - my app converted as a component, the component called by once of another app, so the app sits in div element. where it can't find the images, because of uri mismatch. so to fix i am trying to deploy with new url which can make path correct. hope given some idea

Comment: Maybe check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643134/how-to-replace-assets-urls-in-css-files-to-a-3rd-party-domain-in-case-of-speci